# Как выполнить функцию только один раз?

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

По аналогии с jQuery `.one()`. Например, добавить круг только один раз:

```
for (i=0...

placemarks[i].events.add('click', function(e) {
    var radius = new ymaps.Circle([
        e.get('target').geometry._coordinates,
        10000
    ], {
        fillColor: "#DB709377",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWidth: 0
    });
    yamap.geoObjects.add(radius);
});

...
```

Пробовал в функцию передавать параметр `i` чтобы реализовать через флаги, но он не передается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`IEventManager#once`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IEventManager-docpage/#method_detail__once)

```
placemarks[i].events.once('click', function (e) { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: жесть, пол интернета перерыл, спасибо.